# Sql injection vulnerability check

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection

Just out of curiosity:

I know that values should not be passed to a query due to concern of SQL injection.

I have a query similar to the one below. How can this be used in terms of SQL injection?

```
select * from users u inner join departments d on u.id = d.user_id
where u.id = '#{name}'
```

So the query that is made is

```
 select * from users u inner join departments d on u.id = d.user_id
    where u.id = 'An'
```

That query is just an example, not a working one.

Comment: `'; DROP TABLE users; --` : The `';` closes your query, then there is my drop table, then the `--` turns the rest of your query in to a comment.   ***Use Paramaterised/Prepared Statements***

Comment: If you use parameterized queries/server-bound parameters you avoid injection attacks for good *and* improve performance. In this case parameter values are passed outside the query itself in the RPC call to the server and never become part of the query text itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following for `name`:

```
' UNION SELECT username, password /* more fields */ FROM secrettable WHERE '' = '
```

Comment: `select * from users u inner join departments d on u.id = d.user_id
where u.id = 'UNION SELECT username, password /* more fields */ FROM secrettable WHERE '' = '` this is not going to work

Comment: @themaster You missed the `'` at the start of his "attack"

Comment: @themaster it doesn't matter if *this* query or Bobby Tables (google it) will work. That's the simplest kind of attack - add a single `'` to terminate the previous string and start injecting your code. `' OR 1=1 --` is another string used quite often